# Build the Trinity Hall Prime

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, primes

Based on [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142066/output-the-trinity-hall-prime) and [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420488/what-is-trinity-hall-prime-number). Idea originally come from [a Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQQ8IiTWHhg). The goal is to reproduce the *logic* of Professor McKee when he builds this prime.

Your task is to build the Trinity Hall Prime, at a much lower scale. You are given a single number N greater than 2, representing the length of the prime we need.

## Rules

- N is decomposed into a rectangle W(idth) x H(eight). W and H must be close, so 12 is 4x3 and 16 is 4x4 with W >= H
- The first line got only 8's
- The next lines have 8's in the outer and 1's in the middle
- Each lines have 2 more 1's and 2 less 8's than the previous, except if W is odd, then the second line have only one 1 in the middle
- Once you got your emblem, find the first prime greater than the emblem.
- 2 <= N <= 16
- This is [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art), so newlines must be part of the output.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code, in bytes, wins.

## Test cases:

```
I   Emblem    O
================
2   88        89

3   888       907

4   88        88
    11        19

6   888       888
    818       827

8   8888      8888
    8118      8133

9   888       888
    818       818
    111       159

10  88888     88888
    88188     88213

16  8888      8888
    8118      8118
    1111      1111
    1111      1159
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 194 bytes

```python
n=int(input())
R=range
w=n//max(i*(i*i<=n>1>n%i)for i in R(1,n))
m=0
for i in R(n):m=m*10+1+7*(abs(i%w*2-w+1)//2*w>i-w)
while any(m%p<1for p in R(2,m)):m+=1
m=str(m)
while m:print(m[:w]);m=m[w:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwFET3niIbIYmKxkIL1ngIt@IiBVs/9H@DpqSePo2UQmFWw8ybsbubFzqFQBrIcSD7clyIpNeroceUeE1liebNQUZBq6lTHaUg7svKgAGxnqucYgN1lfyZJBrUKFWVqewiubltHFIv68JnSpRlLX0HhReJn@E5MUM7x9S26iDYL6HOUURIplVkb27l@EtjY9fjLQ6NH8U17gy@GUM4fwA)

too slow for most inputs, especially `x > 8`

-6 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech
-98 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun

Comment: You can save two bytes by defining `j="".join` (adding 9+1 bytes) and replacing `''.join` with `j` (saving 6*2 bytes; 10-12 = -2).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Cool, thanks

Comment: Also, as the input is always one integer, you can replace `eval` with `int` to save one entire byte. Using Python 2, one could entirely remove `eval()` (6 bytes) and the print parentheses (1 byte) to save 7 bytes.

Comment: Looks good, but the output should contains new lines in it! You are almost done.

Comment: @CyrilGandon done

Comment: I suggest you to golf this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833870/128662, because now, for N = 9, it takes more than a minute...

Comment: @CyrilGandon I might, but here on PPCG we usually don't care if things might take like 18 years

Comment: Ok I understand, I'm new to this game :p

Comment: @CyrilGandon That's ok :P Welcome to PPCG by the way! But yeah, except for [tag:fastest-code], as long as it's short that's fine :P :P :P

Comment: [221 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY/BCoJAFEX3foUb8c2o2RgUmeOPiAsDyye956DG5NfbGEQQ3OW553LNMncDH9aVNfIMyOY5gxCe1Zym1LwApQsWmktVcoDiNow@@sj@2PC9BRWzo0mrvZSucfZ6HYa7fkD2/kgWOUX6JDcSOMFECQnNdQIMrMwSGymRppm0JSbW7Xf4aP2GF6DAFGpzmZ8ri0l8dMpNT/MI9G1QbsbtCFW5rcWFNFU2r9f1@AY)

Comment: @LeakyNun o nice thanks

Comment: [198 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY5BCoMwEEX3niIbIYlKjIUWUuNFxEUKtg50xqCW1NOncVEKhdn9/98bv2/TTKcYyQJtHMi/Ni5EFiwphe7NQaaD1lKnO8pB3OeFAQNii6PHyHVJqY22zv4CEgYtSl0XurhI7m4rhzzIpgqFFko1MnRQhSSa4DkyRzvH3Lf6oPgfpSlRJFBhdXKs28Lxu0Djl@Nj7E0YxDW5@mCGGM8f)

Comment: By defining `;R=range` (+ 8 bytes) and replacing all other occurences of `range` with `R` (- 4*3 bytes), you can save -(8-12) = 4 bytes.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Oh cool thanks!

Comment: [192 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tc5BCoMwEIXhfU6RjZCJisZCC7bJIdxKFxa0DnTGoCnB01ulFLr/@d7zaxgnPm0bW@SgkP07KADR2LnjZy@iJWSFcphmiRJZNspkDDhI1OgsO@M4QRBkS/HXMNRkSZsyNelFq@6xKEyirvKYGiiKSkeHeQQRR3z1suNVUeJv5hD8V6gygh1JrdntJcyKfjXVfj6@UlvHO1z3nTbW9207fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>57</s>  56 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒgṖḊ$€2¦j8
Æd:2‘ịÆDðL€©8,8jÇÐĿḊ€ḣ€⁸Ṛ;®ẋ€⁸¤ḣ:@ðFḌÆnDṁ⁸Gḟ⁶
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of characters. As a full program it prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSHO6c93NGl8qhpjdGhZVkWXIfbUqyMHjXMeLi7@3Cby@ENPkCZQystdCyyDrcfnnBkP1AxUOThjsVA8lHjjoc7Z1kfWvdwVzeEe2gJUMbK4fAGt4c7eg635bk83NkIFHZ/uGP@o8Zt////NzYzAAA)**

#### How?

```
ŒgṖḊ$€2¦j8 - Link 1, previous 8-padded-row builder: list current 8-padded-row
           -                                         e.g. [8,8 , 1,1,1 , 8,8]
Œg         - group runs of equal elements                [[8,8],[1,1,1],[8,8]]
       ¦   - sparse application:
      2    - ...to indices: 2
    $€     - ...do: last two links as a monad for €ach:
  Ṗ        -   pop                                       [[8,8],[1,1  ],[8,8]]
   Ḋ       -   dequeue                                   [[8,8],[  1  ],[8,8]]
        j8 - join with eights                             [8,8, 8, 1, 8, 8,8]
           -   (note: from ...818... this yields an extra 8 - dealt with by ḣ€ in Main)

Æd:2‘ịÆDð... - Main link: number, N
Æd           - divisor count of N
  :2         - integer divided by 2
    ‘        - increment
      ÆD     - divisors of N
     ị       - index into (yields W)
        ð    - start a new dyadic chain with W on the left and N on the right...

...L€©8,8jÇÐĿḊ€ḣ€⁸Ṛ;®ẋ€⁸¤ḣ:@ð... - Main link (continued): W, N
   L€                            - length of €ach of implicit range(W) = list of W 1s
     ©                           - (copy to register for later reuse)
      8,8                        - literal [8,8]
         j                       - join -> [8,1,1,...,1,8] with W 1s
           ÐĿ                    - collect inputs until fixed point:
          Ç                      -   call the last link (1) as a monad
             Ḋ€                  - dequeue €ach (remove the leading 8 from each)
                 ⁸               - chain's right argument, N
               ḣ€                - head €ach to index (remove the trailing 8(s))
                  Ṛ              - reverse
                        ¤        - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                    ®            -   recall the [1,1,...W times...,1] from the register
                       ⁸         -   chain's left argument, W
                     ẋ€          -   repeat €ach (making W more rows of W 1s)
                   ;             - concatenate
                          :@     - integer division (sw@p arguments) = N:W = H
                         ḣ       - head to index (gets the first H rows - the mask, M)
                            ð    - start a new dyadic chain with arguments M, N

...FḌÆnDṁ⁸Gḟ⁶ - Main link (continued): M, N
   F          - flatten M
    Ḍ         - from decimal list to number
     Æn       - next prime
       D      - to decimal list
         ⁸    - chain's left argument, M
        ṁ     - mould like (reshape like the mask)
          G   - format as a grid (all digits to characters, add spaces and newlines)
            ⁶ - literal space character
           ḟ  - filter discard (Gḟ⁶ instead of Y as single row results are possible)
              - as a full program: implicit print
```

Comment: Beautiful result, how Jelly succeed to find a prime that fast with 360 digits?

Comment: Jelly uses [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html)'s `nextprime`, which in turn makes use of its `isprime` which, for numbers greater than **2^64**, uses [BPSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) - while this is a probabilistic test no composite false-positives are known. Note that it takes a lot longer if one tries **1350** (times out on TIO).